# Visual Studio 2013 duplicates breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This is not a duplicate question, my question is not answered in other threads. Please read before marking duplicate.

If I mark a breakpoint int Visual Studio 2013, and I leave that in there for several sessions of coding, I find that the breakpoint is duplicated. Sometimes hundreds of times. These are duplicates because they are for the same line of code. I usually click to the left of the line numbers to create my breakpoints.

My question is how do I prevent that from happening? I know how to delete them, I'm just wondering how to prevent them, which I have not seen an answer to.

[image: Duplicates created]

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I know of (that's not a serious bug) that would cause a line breakpoint in C# to have children is if your application is creating multiple (many by the looks of it) [AppDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain(v=vs.110).aspx)'s. As an Application Domain is created, not only is that executable code duplicated, but all of the breakpoints in that code are as well.

So, to prevent the excessive procreation of breakpoints, either stop creating AppDomains or do not set breakpoints in code executing in multiple AppDomains. There is no setting in Visual Studio to prevent this intended behavior.